# Encrypting plain-text passwords and passing variables to xml for display in android

Tags: android, sql, xml, output

Got a couple of questions about this bit of code I've cobbled together.

First, how can I encrypt the password variable so that it's not stored in plain text?

Second, can I pass the 'first' & 'last' variables to an XML element to be displayed on an android device? How would I best go about getting the 'first', 'last' variables to be printed on an android screen?

To be clear I am having no trouble getting this code to work, I just want to know how I can use the output in an android app.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQL{

public static void main(String[] args) {
   /*
    Variables that store our login information and SQL driver information.
    url = database url
    dbName = name of table to query
    driver = name of MySQL driver
    userName = username for SQL server
    password = password for SQL server
   */
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "testdb";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "****";
    String password = "****";

    //Start our exception handling block.
        try {
            //Connect to the driver? I honestly have no idea what this does.
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            //Establish a connection to the SQL server
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
            //Create a statement to be executed.
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            //The query that will be executed.
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Achievments";
            //Create a results set variable that stores the output of our query.
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            //Start a while loop that executes while there are still results in the table?
            while(rs.next()){
                //Retrieve by column name
                String first = rs.getString("ach_names");
                String last = rs.getString("ach_text");

                //Display values
                System.out.print(first);
                System.out.println(last);
            }
            rs.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store your password not in plain text you can use md5. Something like this:

```
public static String md5(String string) {
    byte[] hash;

    try {
        hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Huh, MD5 should be supported?", e);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Huh, UTF-8 should be supported?", e);
    }

    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(hash.length * 2);

    for (byte b : hash) {
        int i = (b & 0xFF);
        if (i < 0x10) hex.append('0');
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString(i));
    }

    return hex.toString();
}
```

About `first` and `last` variables, what do you mean by `pass to an xml element to be displayed`? If you want to programmatically set the text of a TextView you can do like this:

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
yourTextView.setText(first); //or `last` in another textview
```

but maybe i didn't understand what you mean about this `first and last variables`.

Hope the first part of this answer helps.

Comment: I think when I wrote this I was looking for a way to save the database password to a configuration file and read it from there. That's how it works in web apps, at least. As for your second part, that works great thanks!